# share information between 2 classes in different hierarchy

Tags: design-patterns

I'm totally noob, and im studying a design patterns, I want to know which a more elegant way to share data/variables between 2 objects using c++ or java or c#

I have a simple class hierarchy, like that
http://s1285.photobucket.com/user/wandersonp/media/share_data_between_2_objects_zpsd9a626d0.jpg.html

for example how can I communicate the Hero object with monster, and monster to drop_loop object

Thanks

Wanderson

Comment: For better answers, describe your specific application, show the relevant code, your expected results, the actual results you are getting, and describe what you've tried to do to solve the issue.

Comment: Also, use cases are helpful for OO design, and could help clarify your needs here, including where a specific pattern might come in handy.  For example - Use case #5:  Hero stabs monster twice, monster drops loot, hero takes loot.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `Mediator` pattern, which mediates interactions between two objects, like a Hero and Monster.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

`Observer` is often used as a way for one class to communicate events to other interested classes, without the coupling between classes caused by a mediator.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, you're looking for a way for some instance of Hero to being able to get the Loot that the Monster drops via Drop_Loot.

I can't think of a simpler option than this:

- Hero CanAttack any Monster
- Monster CanBeAttacked by any Hero
- Monster can DropLoot to its Location
- Hero CanPickUpLoot from any Location

There's a lot of ways this could be implemented, but it would eliminate the need for some other kind of interaction between Hero and Monster that doesn't involve combat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information about what you intend to do with this data.

Based only on your question, just pass whatever object you want as a parameter to a method / member function of whatever other object you want, e.g. (Java):

```
Hero hero = ...;
Monster monster = ...;
DropLoot loot = ...;

monster.doSomething(hero);
hero.doSomethingElse(loot); 
monster.doWhatever(loot);
```

**However**, most importantly: This question is impossible to answer given the information you've provided. The "correct" "pattern" to use when sharing data depends on what the nature of the data is, how you intend to use it, and how it fits in to your overall application architecture. Use the best tool for the job. Keep your code concise, clear, and maintainable. Using a "pattern" just for the sake of using one is most definitely an anti-pattern.